# JavaFX skips instructions while connecting to server

Tags: javafx, client-server

I have JavaFX application with two scenes. When user fills nick and clicks on button, it should change scenes and then connect to server. But for some unknown reason it first connects to server and change scenes only when it gets respond from server. But it should first do the two set Visible instructions and only then create the Vysilac or am I wrong ?

Here is my code - Button method ( spusteni and cekani are names of the scenes ), Vysilac is class that handles the connection.

```
Vysilac vysilac;

@FXML
private void pripojSe() throws IOException
{
   String nick = textNick.getText();
   if (nick != null && !nick.equals("")) 
   {
    spusteni.setVisible(false);
    cekani.setVisible(true);
    vysilac = new Vysilac(nick);
   }
}


public class Vysilac 
{
private String nick = "Chyba - nick neexistuje";
private Socket socket;
private ObjectOutputStream output;
private ObjectInputStream input;

  Vysilac( String nick) throws IOException
  {
      this.nick = nick;
      socket = new Socket("localhost",33);
      output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
      input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
      //System.out.println(nick);
      output.writeObject(nick);
  }
}
```

Thank for any help or advices:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run long-running operations on a seperate thread. Otherwise you block the JavaFX application thread that is responsible for updating the UI. In this case I'd use a `Task` to get the job done:

```
spusteni.setVisible(false);
cekani.setVisible(true);
Task<Vysilac> task = new Task<Vysilac>() {
    @Override
    protected Vysilac call() throws IOException {
        return new Vysilac(nick);
    }
};

// register state handlers
task.setOnSucceeded(evt -> vysilac = task.getValue());
task.setOnFailed(evt -> {
    // TODO: error handling
});

new Thread(task).start();
```

Comment: Thank this helped me :)